# SFML Clion error CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_directories): target_link_directories called with invalid arguments

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I installed SFML and modified the cmakeList to be able to run an SFML project. I used Msys2 to install mingw and sfml 64bit version. My cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(PHONEBOOK)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window graphics)

add_executable(PHONEBOOK main.cpp contact.cpp contact.h phonebook.cpp phonebook.h)
target_link_directories(PHONEBOOK sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics)
```

When I run the project I get this error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_directories):
target_link_directories called with invalid arguments

mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:255: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `target_link_libraries` instead of `target_link_directories`. As you don't have multiple installations of the sfml library, there is no need to call `target_link_directories`

`target_link_directories` is for [setting the search library path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html).

> Specifies the paths in which the linker should search for libraries
> when linking a given target. Each item can be an absolute or relative
> path, with the latter being interpreted as relative to the current
> source directory. These items will be added to the link command.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing one of the mandatory keywords: <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>.
Eg: `target_link_directories(PHONEBOOK PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics)`